# What's the best way to default to 0 if an integer/double cast fails?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I don't like having to do something like this every time I use `CInt` or `Integer.Parse` (which I realize is costly):

```
Try
  someIntVariable = CInt(someStringVariable)
Catch ex As Exception
  someIntVariable = 0
End Try
```

And I don't like all the lines of code involved with `Integer.TryParse`.  I guess I could create a function that does something like:

```
Function ToInteger(str As String) As Integer
  Dim number As Integer
  Int32.TryParse(str, number)
  Return number
End Function
```

But isn't there already an extension method or something built into .NET that can do this for me in a more elegant way (along the lines of `Nullable(Of T).GetValueOrDefault`)?

Comment: You may want to look at this post: [Integer.TryParse - a better way?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419027/integer-tryparse-a-better-way). TryParse won't throw an exception and as a result works much faster.

Comment: Um. Maybe check the documentation for [`TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx): "*result* ... When this method returns ... zero if the conversion failed" - it sounds like it's already the function you want. (`Double.TryParse` is similarly defined to return zero on failure)

Comment: Since `0` is the default value of `Integer`, you could just omit the entire `If/Else`-block in your method, since when the conversion fails, `TryCast` will set `number` to `0`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Honestly `Integer.TryParse`is the way to go, but you can always hide it behind an extension method if you do not like the syntax.

```
Public Module IntegerExtensions
    <Extension()> _
    Public Function AsIntOrDefault(ByVal valueToParse As String, Optional ByVal defaultValue As Integer = 0) As Integer
        Dim retVal As Integer = 0

        If Not Integer.TryParse(valueToParse, retVal) Then
            retVal = defaultValue
        End If

        Return retVal
    End Function
End Module
```

Which can then be used like this:

```
Public Class Foo
    Public Sub Blah()
        Dim value1 As Integer = "IWillNotParse".AsIntOrDefault() 'Should be 0
        Dim value2 As Integer = "IWillNotParse".AsIntOrDefault(5) 'Should be 5
        Dim value3 As Integer = "123".AsIntOrDefault() 'Should be 123
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: +1 good extension method, which is just using `TryParse` and hiding it.... seems to be what the OP wants....

Comment: You do not need the If Not statement. See my answer.

Comment: @alexw - Actually, you do: `<TestClass()>
Public Class TryParseTests
    <TestMethod()>
    Public Sub TryParseTest()
        Dim foo As Integer = 5
        Integer.TryParse("NoGood", foo)

        Assert.AreEqual(5, foo)
    End Sub

End Class
`  _Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<5>. Actual:<0>._  If you look at the Number class in the .NET framework, it sets the `out result` argument to 0 before it attempts to parse the string.

Comment: @avanek that is correct but the question is "best way to default to 0", therefore a simple `TryParse` is all that is required.

Comment: For my particular implementation it is needed. We're splitting hairs here. If I were to remove my optional parameter, you are absolutely correct. Still, I'm hesitant to lean on a side-effect of an external method. It's the same reason why I prefer `string.Empty` over `""`. Who knows when it could change to something else? Never say never, ha.

Answer (score 5):

You should not use try/catch if you don't need to. There is a lot of overhead involved in throwing an exception.

Instead you can simply use this code (no if/end if statement)

```
Dim value As Integer = 0
Int32.TryParse(stringValue, value)
```

If the string is parse-able then you will have the value, otherwise 0.

Comment: Nobody reads the question.  As I said, I don't want to use TryParse. Its implementation feels hacky for this purpose.  I'll write my own extension method.

Comment: How is TryParse hacky? It exists for the exact problem you describe!

Comment: So how will your extension method work? With a try/catch or TryParse?

Comment: @Doc - people have read your question. Before your edit, your `TryParse` method was overly lengthy given that the behaviour of `TryParse` is to set the result to zero on failure, which is exactly what you seem to be asking for.

Comment: I'd like to be able to do something like `intvar = stringvar.ToIntOrDefault()`

Comment: @doc and would that extension method use the TryParse method like in my example? Or would you still use the slower try/catch method?

Comment: I realize try/catch is costly.  I guess I'm just so used to working with all the built-in extension methods that I was hoping there would be something along those lines that I was missing.

Comment: @Doc `TryParse` is the framework solution to your problem. If you want a one liner you'll have to define your own method (which should just use `TryParse`

Comment: What avanek posted is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could work for you..

```
Function ToInteger(str As String) As Integer
    Dim number As Integer
    If IsNumeric(str) Then
        number = CInt(str)
    Else
        number = 0
    End If
    Return number
End Function
```

Comment: `IsNumeric` is an old VB6 function which is still supported in .NET, but primarily for backwards compatibility.  It's best to avoid those methods when possible.  Also, `CInt` could fail for other reasons.  For instance, it could be numeric, but the number could be too large to convert it to an `Integer`.

Answer (score 0):

Try out `Integer.TryParse(String, Integer)`

You pass the String you want to parse, and the Integer you want to store the result in.

`TryParse` returns a Boolean with whether the parse succeeded or failed. So you could do

```
If Not Integer.TryParse(myNonInt, DestinationInt)
    DestinationInt = 0
End If
```

If the parse succeeds, the value automatically gets stored in `DestinationInt`.

Comment: +1 not sure why you were downvoted except there is no need to set the value if it fails, integers already default to zero.