# Prevent entering a string as an integer in VB

Tags: vb.net, variables, visual-studio-2015

Ok, so I really have no idea how to do this, but how would I prevent a crash when it asks for an integer value and the user gives it a string?

Here's some example code;

```
private sub userInput()
    dim userInputNum As Integer
    userInputNum = InputBox("Enter a number.")
end sub
```

And if the user enters text, it just crashes. So I was wondering if anyone had a solution?

Thanks, I would appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Integer.TryParse`

```
Dim userInputNum As Integer

Dim noInput = Console.ReadLine

If Integer.TryParse(noInput, userInputNum) Then
    Console.WriteLine("Integer accepted")
Else
    Console.WriteLine("Please don't enter non integer values")
End If
```

Comment: An [alternative](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419027/integer-tryparse-a-better-way).

Comment: Might want to strip comas (in US, etc.) so you can accept 1,000 etc.